# Why does selecting text slows down FULL join query so much?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, text

I am testing mysql query response time and I have noticed that once I add only one text type field to select statement, query slows almost 10+ times. As mysql does not support FULL OUTER JOIN statement, therefore I am using following workaround:

```
select 
a.idACCOUNT,p.idPROJECT,p.projectName,t.TRAINING_idPROJECT,t.idTRAINING,t.trainingName,m.MODULE_idTRAINING,m.idMODULE,m.moduleName,c.idCONTENT,c.contentName,
s.idSUBCONTENT
from ACCOUNT as a
   left outer join PROJECT as p on a.idACCOUNT = p.PROJECT_idACCOUNT
   left outer join TRAINING as t on a.idACCOUNT = t.TRAINING_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = t.TRAINING_idPROJECT
   left outer join MODULE as m on a.idACCOUNT = m.MODULE_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = m.MODULE_idPROJECT AND t.idTRAINING = m.MODULE_idTRAINING 
   left outer join CONTENT as c on a.idACCOUNT = c.CONTENT_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = c.CONTENT_idPROJECT AND t.idTRAINING = c.CONTENT_idTRAINING AND 
m.idMODULE = c.CONTENT_idMODULE 
   left outer join SUBCONTENT as s on a.idACCOUNT = s.SUBCONTENT_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = s.SUBCONTENT_idPROJECT AND t.idTRAINING = s.SUBCONTENT_idTRAINING 
AND m.idMODULE = s.SUBCONTENT_idMODULE AND c.idCONTENT =    s.SUBCONTENT_idCONTENT
WHERE a.idACCOUNT='1'
union all
select 
a.idACCOUNT,p.idPROJECT,p.projectName,t.TRAINING_idPROJECT,t.idTRAINING,t.trainingName,m.MODULE_idTRAINING,m.idMODULE,m.moduleName,c.idCONTENT,c.contentName,
s.idSUBCONTEN
from ACCOUNT as a
   right outer join PROJECT as p on a.idACCOUNT = p.PROJECT_idACCOUNT
   right outer join TRAINING as t on a.idACCOUNT = t.TRAINING_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = t.TRAINING_idPROJECT
   right outer join MODULE as m on a.idACCOUNT = m.MODULE_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = m.MODULE_idPROJECT AND t.idTRAINING = m.MODULE_idTRAINING 
   right outer join CONTENT as c on a.idACCOUNT = c.CONTENT_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = c.CONTENT_idPROJECT AND t.idTRAINING = c.CONTENT_idTRAINING AND 
m.idMODULE = c.CONTENT_idMODULE 
   right outer join SUBCONTENT as s on a.idACCOUNT = s.SUBCONTENT_idACCOUNT AND p.idPROJECT = s.SUBCONTENT_idPROJECT AND t.idTRAINING = 
s.SUBCONTENT_idTRAINING AND m.idMODULE = s.SUBCONTENT_idMODULE AND c.idCONTENT = s.SUBCONTENT_idCONTENT
WHERE a.idACCOUNT is null;
```

Above query contains only varchars up to 255 and INT 11 fields, this query returns results with speed of: Query took 0.0010 sec.

**Now if I will add to Select section at least one text field query time jumps to 0.0337 sec, single tests somtimes even reach 0.1 sec**

It is not critical however running separate query for text field is much faster with speed of:  Query took 0.0004 sec.

This seems to me that it will be faster to separate two queries and have specific query for text fields such as comments and separate query for varchars and other indexes.

Now my questions is why does it affect the query time that much to add only one text filed in select part ? And why separate query runs within expected time frame ?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: What do you mean with "Add to select at lease one text filed"?

Comment: a.idACCOUNT and all other columns are varchars and INT types. Adding one column that is text type effects in slow down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TEXT` columns are stored off-page, while `VARCHAR` are stored in-line (if smaller than a reasonable limit). Typically this means reading additional disk pages to retrieve the `TEXT` data.

Obviously, if the `TEXT column contains long strings, just having to retrieve "more data" could dramatically slow down the query.

Comment: Surfing the topic I also came across the in-line versus off-page discussion. Can you tell what in-line means?

Comment: Off-page storage means it's not stored physically in the same spot as the rest of the row, but rather what's stored is a pointer to the overflow page that has the text.  They are also typically compressed, which adds significantly to access time.  Conversely in-line means it's physically in-line with the other fields on the row.

Comment: @Yak. Thank you for the answer. Based on your statement I conducted additional tests and when changing text column to varchar(8000) I do experience the same slow down - so you are very right about off-page situation. However now, I do not fully understand why if running separate query (without Join) that pulls cols with different types query time is normal. Just to point out text cols that I am playing with have only few words added. Additionally, now I have as well discovered that slow down is only related to FULL JOIN, if I test this with only RIGHT/LEFT OUTER JOIN query time is normal.

Comment: This is certainly related to the facts that (A) `MEMORY` tables do not support the `TEXT` type, therefore if a temporary table needs to be created during the course of the query, it can only be written on disk; (B) (wild-guessing here) the version of your query using a FULL JOIN needs to create a temporary table to hold the records matching the join condition, whereas a LEFT JOIN will select all rows from the left table (hence, no temporary table is needed). An `EXPLAIN` of both versions might confirm this.